# Convexity, Monotonicity, Positivity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, monotone-functions

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable convex function, then we know that its gradient is monotone:
$$
r(x,y) := (x-y)^T(\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)) \geq 0\,, \quad \text{for all} \quad x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
I am interested in the function $r(x,y)$. By inspection, the following three properties hold:

1. $r(x,y) \geq 0$
2. $r(x,x) = 0$
3. $r(x,y) = r(y,x)$.

General question: what else interesting can be said about the function $r(x,y)$?

Specific question: Does (or *when* does) $r(x,y)$ admit a factorization
$$
r(x,y) = (h(x)-h(y))^{\sf T}(h(x)-h(y))
$$
for some vector-valued mapping $h$?

Comment: You can factor if $f$ is a quadratic, e.g., $\tfrac{1}{2}\langle x,Ax\rangle$ using the square root of $A$. I doubt you can factor others. What would you do for $f(x)=\exp(x)$ for instance?

Comment: I agree the factorization does not look promising. Still interested though in what else can be said about this function.